# Collection View prepareForReuse dosent call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height, uicollectionviewcell

I have strange problem in my project: 
hierarchy:

> TableView > tableViewCell ( in one cell I have CollectionView)

I have some cell's and when `tableViewCell` have height like `collectionView ContentSize`, then `CollectionViewCell's` doesn't use `prepareForReuse` function.

Here is my question. When `CollectionView` Height have same like `ContentSize` then function `prepareForReuse` doesn't call and collection View load all of cells ?

thanks

Comment: Add the code of both UICollectionViewCell and UITableViewCell.

Comment: `prepareForReuse` is called on a cell that was already used, and now is being reused (using `dequeueCell`).. so if all the cells are visible, there is no reuse, each cell is a new, non-reused instance

Comment: For checking `prepareForReuse` work, let add more data to the table view.